# Working With Multiple Settings

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I try to add multiple settings for my django project. Separate settings for devserver and production.

For this I removed my settings.py file and  the new file structure would look like this:

```
mysite/
 |-- mysite/
 |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |-- settings/
 |    |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- base.py
 |    |    |-- development.py
 |    |    |-- production.py   
 |    |-- urls.py
 |    +-- wsgi.py
 +-- manage.py
```

I filled in base.py, development.py, production.py and replaced the path to the root of the project at base.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

to ==>

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

And it working good at my local server when I start

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=mysite.settings.development
```

but when I do the same settings in production I get Internal server error. My server works for Nginx and Uwsgi.

Comment: Checkout [converge](https://github.com/shon/converge) which makes it more easier to handle settings in different environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done this `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))` correctly.

**You need to do:**

In `settings/__init__.py` file put the below codes.

```
from .production import *

try:
    from .local import *
except:
    pass
```

Now, run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

It will work fine.

Comment: @lepiloff, You can select the answer, if it helped. Thanks.